# Accessing and caching attributes

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following manager class that handles access and caching attributes from classes. I am a bit worried about the caching mechanism.

Is there a better way of handling it?

```
public static class AttributeManager
    {
        private static Dictionary<Type, Attribute> _cache = new Dictionary<Type, Attribute>();

        public static AttributeType GetAttribute<AttributeType>(Type type)
            where AttributeType : Attribute
        {

            if (_cache.ContainsKey(type))
            {
                return (AttributeType)_cache[type];
            }

            var attr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(type, typeof(AttributeType));

            if (attr != null)
            {
                _cache.Add(type, attr);
                return (AttributeType)attr;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"The specified attribute: {nameof(AttributeType)} was not found.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your application really requires attribute caching? Have you measured its performance? Attribute caching is a rather rare operation - I wouldn't bother if it wasn't necessary - see: [To cache or not to cache - GetCustomAttributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612122/to-cache-or-not-to-cache-getcustomattributes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let’s define an extension method on `Type`:

```
public static class AttributeCache
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Attributes<T>(this Type type)
        where T : Attribute => Cache
            .GetOrAdd(type, t => t.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<Attribute>().ToArray())
            .OfType<T>();        

    static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Attribute[]> Cache { get; } = 
        new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Attribute[]>();
}
```

Demo:

```
foreach (var a in typeof(MyCass).Attributes<TestAttribute>())
    Console.WriteLine(a.MyProp);
```

Answer (score 2):

A type may contain more that one attributes... therefore it is not sufficient to use the type as key. It must be a combination of type and attribute type.

---

The static variable `_cache` should be `readonly`.

---

The following can be realized with just one lookup:

```
// two lookups:
if (_cache.ContainsKey(type))
{
    return (AttributeType)_cache[type];
}

// one lookup:
Attribute attribute;
if (_cache.TryGetValue(type, out attribute)
{
    return (AttributeType)attribute;
}
```

---

Consider to return null if the attribute is not available. However, you should not cast (`(AttributeType)_cache[type];`) the cached value. Use either `_cache[type] as AttributeType` if you want to return null or throw a custom exception - otherwise an `InvalidCasteException` will be thrown.

Example that produces an `InvalidCastException`:

```
void Main()
{
    var attributeA = AttributeManager.GetAttribute<AAttribute>(typeof(MyCass));
    // thrwows an InvalidCastException
    var attributeB = AttributeManager.GetAttribute<BAttribute>(typeof(MyCass));
}

[AAttribute("test")]
[BAttribute("test")]
public class MyCass
{
}

public class BAttribute : Attribute
{
    public BAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class AAttribute : Attribute
{
    public AAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set;}
}

public static class AttributeManager
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, Attribute> _cache = new Dictionary<Type, Attribute>();

    public static AttributeType GetAttribute<AttributeType>(Type type)
        where AttributeType : Attribute
    {
        Attribute attribute;
        if (_cache.TryGetValue(type, out attribute))
        {
            return (AttributeType)attribute;
        }

        var attr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(type, typeof(AttributeType));

        if (attr != null)
        {
            _cache.Add(type, attr);
            return (AttributeType)attr;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"The specified attribute: {nameof(AttributeType)} was not found.");
        }
    }
}
```